# How avoid Entity Framework 6 populating new databases?

Tags: entity-framework-6

Is there a native Entity Framework way to create a database (LocalDB) without populating it with the tables defined in my DbContext class (code first)?  (I want to use my own database creation script, with default values, etc, and I want to be able to clear it out beforehand using `context.Database.Delete()`.)

If I use `context.Database.Create()` then EF will populate the database with tables.  If not then no database exists and I cannot connect to it to run my database creation SQL.

I am providing a connection string like this:

```
data source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;integrated security=True;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\\FileName.mdf;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base DbContext instance that uses the same database, and use it to do the recreation.

```
var my_context = new MyDbContext(connection_string);
var creater_context = new DbContext(connection_string);
creater_context.Database.Delete();
creater_context.Database.Create();
// now use my_context on the database.
```